# paho mqtt python client frequently disconnecting with error code 7 "The connection was lost" after sending state and events to GCP IoT Core

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, mqtt, paho, google-cloud-iot

**EDIT:** In an initial version of this question I was using the Python paho-mqtt client version `paho-mqtt 1.5.1`. The error message I received with that version was `on_disconnect 1: Out of memory. error code 1`. It was recommended to install the newer version (1.6) of the paho-mqtt client and rerun the code. I did that and still encounter the same spontaneous disconnection, yet the newer version has more descriptive error messages, With the 1.6 version I receive the disconnection error code 7, which means that "The connection was lost".

I am simulating an IoT device. As part of this simulation I have created a Messenger class, which, when instantiated, communicates with a virtual device on Google Cloud's IoT core with the MQTT protocol. The client I am using frequently disconnects leading to lost messages. I am hoping to find a way to prevent the client from randomly disconnecting.

The client used for this communication, which is embedded in the Messenger class, is the [python paho mqtt client](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/python/index.php).
The client id is derived from the project_id, cloud_region, registry_id and device_id using the following code
`client_id = "projects/{}/locations/{}/registries/{}/devices/{}".format(project_id, cloud_region, registry_id, device_id)`

The client communicates with IoT core in three different ways:

1. It publishes data to the events topic

```py
sub_topic = "events"
mqtt_topic = "/devices/{}/{}".format(self.device_id, sub_topic)
client.publish(mqtt_topic, payload, qos=1)
```

2. It subscribes to the virtual device's config topic

```py
mqtt_config_topic = "/devices/{}/config".format(self.device_id)
sub_status = client.subscribe(mqtt_config_topic, qos=1)
```

3. It sends state information to the device's state topic at a frequency no greater than once every 12 seconds. (Google Cloud recommends no more than once every 10 seconds so I added a few more seconds for wiggle room).

```py
sub_topic = "state"
mqtt_topic = "/devices/{}/{}".format(self.device_id, sub_topic)
payload = json.dumps(new_state)
client.publish(mqtt_topic, payload, qos=0)
```

Initially I noticed that not all of the data sent to be published to the events topic was sent. After examining the log file, I determined the issue was caused by the frequent disconnects of the client. The error code given for the client disconnect is 1, which is technically an "out of memory" error, but also occurs when GCP disconnects the client. I think the issue lies with GCP disconnecting the client, but I am not entirely sure

Here is an excerpt of a log file:

```sh
DEBUG Controller4.testA [04/Nov/2021:12:54:57.862] new client created
DEBUG Controller4.testA [04/Nov/2021:12:54:57.865] Publishing state to /devices/<DeviceID>/state
DEBUG Controller4.testA [04/Nov/2021:12:54:57.867] Sending PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m2), 'b'/devices/<DeviceID>/state'', ... (197 bytes)
DEBUG Controller4.testA [04/Nov/2021:12:54:57.870] Not publishing state: Previous state update 0:00:00.004303 seconds ago
DEBUG Controller4.testA [04/Nov/2021:12:54:57.870] on_publish client: <paho.mqtt.client.Client object at 0x15bf73670> userdata: None mid: 2
DEBUG Controller4.testA [04/Nov/2021:12:54:57.871] Sending PUBACK (Mid: 1)
DEBUG Controller4.testA [04/Nov/2021:12:54:57.947] Received CONNACK (0, 0)
DEBUG Controller4.testA [04/Nov/2021:12:54:57.951] on_connect Connection Accepted.
DEBUG Controller4.testA [04/Nov/2021:12:54:57.976] Received SUBACK
DEBUG Controller4.testA [04/Nov/2021:12:54:57.976] Subscribed: (1,)
DEBUG Controller4.testA [04/Nov/2021:12:54:57.978] Received PUBLISH (d0, q1, r0, m1), '/devices/<DeviceID>/config', ...  (20 bytes)
INFO Controller4.testA [04/Nov/2021:12:54:57.979] Received new state message '{"osmo": 6, "pH": 4}' on topic '/devices/<DeviceID>/config' with Qos 1
DEBUG Controller4.testA [04/Nov/2021:12:54:57.980] Not publishing state: Previous state update 0:00:00.114637 seconds ago
DEBUG Controller4.testA [04/Nov/2021:12:54:57.981] Sending PUBACK (Mid: 1)
DEBUG Controller4.testA [04/Nov/2021:12:55:01.958] on_disconnect 7: The connection was lost. error code 7<paho.mqtt.client.Client object at 0x15bf60b80>None
```

I am currently working on a virtual private cloud, but I am not sure that matters.

Why does the client keep disconnecting? How can I further troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: How frequent are the disconnections? A common cause is another connection being established with the same client ID (this causes the broker to drop any existing connections and if both connections auto-reconnect it becomes a loop). If it's not that a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help (so we can see how you are connecting etc).

Comment: The disconnections are about once every 30 seconds. I do not have multiple connections being made with the same client. I will try to develop a minimal, reproducible example soon.

Comment: The disconnections might be occurring because the device might be going into a suspend state and that causes the WIFI stack to go in suspend / disconnected.